# Evaluating the $H_0$ of a contigency table

Tags: probability, bayesian, categorical-data, simulation

I have a 2 way contigency table with variables $A=\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2\}$. I have the observed cell frequencies $O_1=a_1b_1$, $O_2=a_1b_2$, $O_3=a_2b_1$ and $O_4=a_2b_2$. My null hypothesis is that $A$ and $B$ are independent variables

I am interested to evaluate what is the probability of observing each of the cells given that $H_0$ is true, $\text{Pr}(O_1=a_1b_1|H_0)$. How can I calculate this probability? Is there a bayesian approach or a simulation procedure that could help me obtain this probability?